Какая суммарная полоса пропускания входящего и исходящего трафика у 8-жильной витой пары + Гигабитной сетевой карты?
Если у провайдера тариф - 1 Гигабит, в хату проведен 8-жильный провод, который входит в Гигабитную сетевую карту TP-Link TG-3468.
В теории лимит полосы пропускания будет - 500 мегабит входящего трафика и 500 мегабит исходящего трафика (одновременного)?
Или 1000+1000 ?
И куда в моем случае будет упор? ("горлышко")

В целом, согласен с ответом eri.
Гигабитный линк даёт ~900Мбит дуплекса на Windows, и немного больше Линуксах, при настройках по умолчанию.
Но есть много нюансов с провайдерами. Из личного опыта:

Провайдер называет тариф Гигабит, но в условиях написано, что 1000 Мбит - суммарная максимальная скорость для входящего и исходящего трафика. Следовательно скорость режется провайдером до 500;
Скорость провайдером не ограничивается, но домовой коммутатор провайдера имеет только гигабитные порты, следовательно весь гигабитный порт будет делиться между соседями. Тут всё зависит от обстоятельств;
Местный небольшой провайдер даёт гигабитные тарифы, домовое оборудование - 10Gbit коммутаторы, но единственный аплинк до вышестоящего провайдера 4 гигабита. В итоге локальные ресурсы норм, но с интернетом беда.

Если провайдер нормальный и удачное стечение обстоятельств, то Speedtest может показать больше 800 Мбит и торрент может раскачаться до 600 Мбит.

Около 900Mbit входящего + 900Mbit исходящего. Можно чуть больше при использовании Jambo Frames (но слоны не пройдут в интернет  не порезанными).

Прошу прощения, наверное, имелись в виду Jumbo frames? В старые времена, у некоторых провайдеров с авторизацией по PPPoE, это помогало обходить ограничения скорости в тарифах.

да. не думаю фокус сработает на современном оборудовании чтоб получить сверх положенного, но может снизить издержки эзернет
